# Invalid Bundle. Your binary, {Bundle name}, has a 64-bit architecture slice

Tags: swift, xcode, app-store-connect

> ERROR ITMS-90502: "Invalid Bundle. Your binary, '{Bundle id}', has a 64-bit architecture slice, so you must include the "arm64" value for the UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities key in your Xcode project. Learn more (https://developer.apple.com/library/content/documentation/General/Reference/InfoPlistKeyReference/Articles/iPhoneOSKeys.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009252-SW3)."

I keep getting this error every time I try to upload a version to the store, note that it includes the iMessage extension.

I try all the solutions:

1. Change Build Active Architecture Only to yes
2. Setting Required device capabilities for all targets.

Also in Xcode, it shows that it really supports arm64!

[image]

Xcode version 13.0

Comment: Is this a Mac app or an iOS app?

Comment: it's an ios app.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I have fixed this issue by adding

**UIRequiredDeviceCapabilities    armv7  arm64**

to Info.plist to all targets

Answer (score 0):

Adding arm64 to RequiredDeviceCapabilities info pList didn't work for me. Instead, I had to set the Deployment Info in the sticker extension to iOS 10.0, even though the project and app were set to iOS 13.0.

[image: Sticker Pack Extension]

You may also see a related error:

> ITMS-90747: Architecture incompatible with MinimumOSVersion. The app
> bundle specifies a MinimumOSVersion of '13.0' but contains a 32-bit
> architecture that is unsupported on iOS 12 and later.

In which case, the fix is the same, set the deployment info to iOS 10.0 for the sticker pack extension.